# Why Chrome use sometimes a same process for at least two different tab?

Tags: google-chrome, task-manager

I have noticed in the Chrome task manager that some tabs was linked and sharing the same process:

[image]

There is no link between these pages, one is not the referer of the other, and they have not the same origin.

What is the reason of that?

There is several [processes model](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/process-models) in chromium, but this does not match any of these models

Comment: How many tabs do you have open? What version of Chrome/OS?

Comment: Not seeing this on Windows 7/Chrome 42.

Comment: I have a lot of tabs open! Seeing this on Chrome42/Ubuntu15.04 and ChromeOS.

Comment: I also noticed this with Chrome on Linux Mint.